# How to correctly large state updates in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am writing a small ReactNative application that allows users to invite people to events.

The design includes a list of invitees, each of which is accompanied by a checkbox used to invite/uninvite said invitee. Another checkbox at the top of the list that performs a mass invite/uninvite on all invitees simultaneously. Finally a button will eventually be used to send out the invites.

Because the state of each of these elements depends changes made by the other I often need to re-render my entire UI whenever the user takes action on one of them. But while this works correctly it is causing me quite a few performance issues, [as shown in this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NnDcyLKmGrcQYIn3vfpRU64c0ma9hKVE/view?usp=sharing)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Title, 
    Content, Footer, FooterTab, 
    Button, Left, Right, 
    Center, Body, Text, Spinner, Toast, Root , CheckBox, ListItem, Thumbnail} from 'native-base';

import { FlatList, View } from 'react-native';

export default class EventInviteComponent extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.disableYellowBox = true; 

    this.state = {
        eventName: "Cool Outing!",
        invitees:[]
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        this.state.invitees[i] = { 
            name: "Peter the " + i + "th",
            isSelected: false,
            thumbnailUrl: 'https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple111/v4/62/08/7e/62087ed8-5016-3ed0-ca33-50d33a5d8497/source/512x512bb.jpg'
        }
      }


    this.toggelSelectAll = this.toggelSelectAll.bind(this)
}

toggelSelectAll(){
    let invitees = [...this.state.invitees].slice();
    let shouldInviteAll = invitees.filter(invitee => !invitee.isSelected).length != 0

    let newState = this.state;
    newState = invitees.map(function(invitee){
        invitee.isSelected = shouldInviteAll;
        return invitee;
        });
    this.setState(newState);
}


render() {

    let invitees = [...this.state.invitees];

    return (
        <Root>
            <Container>

                <Content>
                    <Text>{this.state.eventName}</Text>

                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: 50, marginLeft:10, marginTop:20}}>
                        <CheckBox 
                    checked={this.state.invitees.filter(invitee => !invitee.isSelected).length == 0}
                    onPress={this.toggelSelectAll}/>
                        <Text style={{marginLeft:30 }}>Select/deselect all</Text>
                    </View>

                    <FlatList
                    keyExtractor={(invitee, index) => invitee.name}
                    data={invitees}
                    renderItem={(item)=> 
                        <ListItem avatar style={{paddingTop: 20}}>
                            <Left>
                              <Thumbnail source={{ uri: item.item.thumbnailUrl}} />
                            </Left>
                            <Body>
                                <Text>{item.item.name}</Text>
                                <Text note> </Text>
                            </Body>
                            <Right>
                                <CheckBox 
                                checked={item.item.isSelected}/>
                            </Right>
                        </ListItem>}/>

                </Content>

                <Footer>
                    <FooterTab>
                        <Button full
                         active={invitees.filter(invitee => invitee.isSelected).length > 0}>
                            <Text>Invite!</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </FooterTab>
                </Footer>

            </Container>
        </Root>);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a few suggestions here: #1. You don't need to clone the array in render function. #2. The state should not contain everything like you did. I think it could be the array of ids of invitees. #3. It's weird that FlatList did not improve anything here. You may want to get the reference to the checkboxes and toggle each instead of re-render everything. Hope it could help

Answer (score 1):

In your code, in class method `toggelSelectAll() {...}` you modify the state directly by using `this.state = ...`, which is something to be avoided. Only use `this.state = ...` in your class `constructor() {...}` to initialize the state, and you should only use `this.setState({...})` to update the state anywhere else.

Not sure if this should help your performance issues, but try replacing `toggelSelectAll()` with the following:

```
toggelSelectAll() {
  const {invitees} = this.state;

  const areAllSelectedAlready = invitees.filter(({isSelected}) => !isSelected).length === 0;

  this.setState({
    invitees: invitees.map(invitee => ({
      ...invitee,
      isSelected: !areAllSelectedAlready
    }))
  });
}
```

Good luck! And, let me know if you would like me to refactor your above code to remove the 2nd `this.state = ...` in your constructor (which, once again, should be avoided when writing React).

Comment: You are right. There was a typo. I corrected it now but no, it doesn't help improving the performance.

Comment: ah! understood.

Nonetheless, I'm not really sure why you are having performance issues; it is very strange as updating just 50 records should not cause this issue.

Comment: For some reason the checkbox animation is being blocked by the JS thread.

Comment: could there possibly be a problem with the `<CheckBox>` `checked` prop? maybe the calculation using `invitees.filter()` is slow?

Comment: as well, try adding a console.log() statement someplace --> maybe a large & unnecessary loop takes place and the render() method gets called 1000+ times in one of the components?

Comment: Nope, `render` is only called once per state update. Also each list item is only created once per invitee.

Comment: very strange... sorry I couldn't be more helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

- Dividing your code by creating multiple components, so you won't have a massive `render()`
- Using Redux to store invitee / global state, so you can choose which components should re-render in case of modifications

That's a good way to learn React Native!